# How do you ask a user for their name and display the first and last character in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried using this piece of code:

```
name = input("What is your full name? ")
print(name[0:-1])
```

but it didn't work. Instead of displaying the first and last character, it would delete the last letter and display the rest.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So, why do you not want to use a variable? Without it this is going to be very hacky.

Comment: Why is it wrapped in `len()`? That will give you the length of the input. `[0:-1]` will slice the list too, not give you the first and last letter.

Comment: `print((lambda s: s[0] + s[-1])(input("What is your full name? ")))` would work, but does that count as using no intermediate variable? It is basically the same as using `itemgetter`, though.

Comment: There are already better ways provided, but here is another way as you asked. `import numpy` and `print(''.join(numpy.roll(list(input()), -1)[:-3:-1]))`. I had wanted to use `collections.deque(data).rotate(-1)` but it doesn't return a value so you'd need to use a variable. Numpy roll does the same sort of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do:

```
name = input("What is your full name? ")
print(name[0] + name[len(name)-1])
```

Putting 0 would display the first letter and because "len" counts the number of letters and the variable (name) already has stored information, subtracting 1 would give you the last character.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do it without declaring any variables you could use [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) and then join first and last returned value.

```
from operator import itemgetter

print(''.join(itemgetter(0,-1)(input("What is your full name? "))))
```

Without importing libraries

```
print(''.join(map(input("What is your full name? ").__getitem__, (0,-1))))
```

or as @Graipher suggested:

```
print((lambda s: s[0] + s[-1])(input("What is your full name? ")))
```

---

**Output:**

```
What is your full name? hello
ho
```